# Почему не пингуется сайт?

Tags: python, tkinter, ping

Почему у меня не пингуется сайт в этом коде с помощью pythonping? В чём здесь проблема

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pythonping import ping
import string
import secrets

win = Tk()
win.geometry("375x250")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title("All-in-one")

# defs
def default():
    def ping():
        def showping():
            try:
                win.geometry("450x200")
                myLabel4 = Label(win, text="Ожидайте...", font=("Montserrat", 11))
                myLabel4.pack()
                win.update()
                myLabel4.destroy()
                win.geometry("450x190")
                tk.messagebox.showinfo("Пинг", "- Результаты пинга:\n" + str(ping(Input1.get(), verbose=True, count=5)))
            except:
                myLabel4.destroy()
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "- Произошла ошибка, проверьте правильность написания IP-адреса или ссылки")
        myLabel1.destroy()
        myButton1.destroy()
        myButton2.destroy()
        myButton3.destroy()
        Input1 = StringVar()
        myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 20))
        myLabel2.pack()
        myLabel3 = Label(win, text="Введите ссылку или IP-адрес", font=("Montserrat", 18))
        myLabel3.pack()
        myInput1 = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 15), textvariable=Input1, justify=LEFT, width=30, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
        myInput1.pack(ipady=2)
        myButton4 = Button(win, text="Принять", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=showping)
        myButton4.pack(ipady=2, pady=12)
        win.geometry("450x190")
    myLabel1 = Label(win, text="Способы", font=("Montserrat", 20))
    myLabel1.pack()
    myButton1 = Button(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17, command=ping)
    myButton1.pack(pady=6)
    myButton2 = Button(win, text="Длина текста", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton2.pack(pady=6)
    myButton3 = Button(win, text="Генератор паролей", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton3.pack(pady=6)

# widgets
default()

win.mainloop()
```

Я хочу чтобы программа выводила в MessageBox 5 результатов пинга того сайта, который ввёл пользователь в Entry (myInput1)

Comment: Как минимум, ваша функция `def ping():` перекрывает функцию `from pythonping import ping` потому что название совпадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, если вывести Exception:

```
ping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

Отсюда можно будет догадаться, что в `ping(Input1.get(),...)` позвалось явно что-то не то, и заметить, что у вас есть 2 разные функции под одним именем: `from pythonping import ping` и `def ping():`.

Но даже если это поправить, то я получаю другую ошибку:

```
[WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа
```

Хм... Отправка ICMP пакетов требует права администратора?

Comment: В `Google Colab` этот пинг нормально работает. Возможно в винде запрещается кому ни попадя пинговать )